# Adding background video in HTML section by java script

Tags: javascript, wordpress, video, background

Hy There! I am trying to add background video in a section on WordPress website. I can't edit that page code so i have to add it through JavaScript. This is website page link:http://listchicagocondo.com/index.php/new-form/. In first section background i want to add video.

I have tried adding jQuery attribute but nothing worked.

Comment: `In first section background i want to add video` but you did not say which code belongs to this _"first section"_ so we can help you. Just [**update your question**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64679735/edit) with the code that needs editing. To play a video you need to use a `<video>` tag so make sure you create one in the first section's code...

Comment: From a quick look at your page code I'm not seeing a `<div>` where you can put a `<video>` tag. Maybe use JS to **(a)** create a div and put a video there **(b)** then position the div where you need it to be.

Answer (score 1):

try this , you may add more attribute as per your requirement

```
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
// Create the text node for video element.
    var video = document.createElement('video');  
  // Create the text node for source element.
     var source = document.createElement('video');  
//add id attribute on video tag    
    video.setAttribute('id', 'video');

    source.src='video.mp4';
      video.appendChild(source);
    
});
</script>
```

Comment: Shantun Parmar, Thanks for response. But i did not understand what you are trying to say, i am just fresh on wordpress development.